# ubuntu iptables DROP action has no effect

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I installed **zentyal** web panel for ubuntu,
And after a monument I removed it.
*After remove zentyal, iptables seems work not properly.*

**DROP has no effect**
Run following code has no effect to block port 22.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.9.0/24 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables-save
service ufw restart
```

After, client 218.78.1.23 also can access ssh service.

**iptables been empty after reboot**
Run following code before reboot server.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables-save
service ufw restart
```

After reboot, run following code.

```
iptables -L | grep DROP
```

will display nothing.

```
iptables-save | grep DROP
```

also nothing display.

I don't know how to fix this issue now. m(_ _)m THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are not using the available tools in an appropriate way. The tool `iptables-save` will dump your current ruleset from memory to stdout. It will not save the rules in any file unless you explicitly redirect its output.

Also, you are mixing two things: using iptables tool and using ufw at the same time. I recommend to go all the way with one tool (eventually ufw will use iptables). This will be less confusing for you.

If you want to go with iptables alone. You need to use it like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables-save > /path/some/file
iptables-restore /path/some/file
```

The restore command need to be included in a script that will be invoked during system startup.

Comment: when I running `ufw disable` iptables take effect, and I wrote iptables rule into **rc.local** Thanks!